# Ad ID Hiding in Android

Tags: android, admob

I have Ad in my application, So when I upload application into google play, if some one reverse engineered the code, I guess they can see my Ad Id. So is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: what do you mean by hide add ids

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Hide in the sense, when some one reverse engineered, they can find my code, also the Ad Id inside the code, So how Can I protect the Ad Id from that? Encryption or any other ways?

Comment: Now don't worry about this because as google announced when you upload apk on play store google itself ofsculate the apk . even any body try to reverse engineering on apk will not get readable code.

Comment: @shijuB  Am programatically adding the Ad to my Application, like         adview = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER,"a14e176c0a170e2");  So I guess we need to give the Id as an input parameter like the sample above. Isn't it?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia you're a little too trusting in the outcome of code obfuscation and readability, particularly if you think it will help to make reading a string constant difficult. Someone that wants to reverse engineer an APK can get a lot of information even when the binary has been obfuscated.

Comment: @AshMv you would need to not store your ID as a directly readable constant anywhere in your application. You could perhaps encrypt it and store the encrypted value but then your app would need to decrypt it (which means storing a key to decrypt it somewhere). You could store it on a web server and let your application retrieve it. Both of these are silly though; why don't you describe the problem you are wanting to solve, rather than asking how to perform the solution you've already decided on? Perhaps there are better ways to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, someone reverse engineering your app could find your ad unit id.

They don't gain much from this. If they were to start using it in their apps then you would be credited with any traffic they generated, so it is not something a malicious developer would do.

The worst scenario would be if you had someone trying to cripple your advertising money flow by generating enough clicks considered fraudulent that the ad network banned your account. This seems highly unlikely unless you have a mortal enemy.

But if you are feeling really paranoid then your can mitigate the danger but splitting your ad unit id into more than one part and only concatenating them when you use it.

Comment: So usually, nobody encrypt the Id? Am new to this.

Comment: No, there is nothing to gain.

Comment: @AshMv You could get more money :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; // replace with own adUint id.
```

1. Declare string
2. And use this string ad id in (.onLoad) ad method. here is the example

   InterstitialAd.load(this,AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest,
   new InterstitialAdLoadCallback()

->here you go full security.